# How do I retain/access the custom log files from a completed cronjob?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a cronjob that is completing and outputting several log files.

I want to persist these files and be able access them after the pod has succeeded.

I've found I can access the stdout with `oc logs -f <pod>`, but I really need to access the log files.

I'm aware Openshift 2 apparently had an environment variable location OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR that log files were written to, but Openshift 3.5 doesn't appear to have this.

What's my best way of logging and accessing the logs from the CronJob after the pod has succeeded and finished?

Comment: Ensure any logging is sent to stdout/stderr rather than to a file. If it is too hard to change the application to not write to a file, then change the path for the log file to be ``/proc/1/fd/1``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Okay so if I change my file log to /proc/1/fs/1/log.errors. How do I then access them?

Comment: Not ``/proc/1/fs/1/log.errors`` if you used that. The log file has to be called ``/proc/1/fs/1``. Don't go adding ``log.errors`` at the end. That is a file path, not a directory. If you do it correctly, they should then appear in ``oc logs`` output.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have a delete list file that I need to access after the CronJob pod has finished running. Is there no way of doing this, without dumping it out to stdout/stderr?

Comment: My understanding is that results of jobs need to be uploaded to somewhere outside of the context of the container. Thus stored in an attached persistent volume, uploaded to S3, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

After a `Job` runs to completion, the `Pod` terminates, but it is not automatically deleted. Since it has completed, you need to use `-a` to see it. Once you have the `Pod` name, `kubectl logs` works as you would expect.

```
$ kubectl get pods -a
NAME                                    READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
curator-1499817660-6rzmf                0/1       Completed   0          28d
$ kubectl logs curator-1499817660-6rzmf
2017-07-12 00:01:10,409 INFO ...
```

Comment: I need to see custom files that my application will be writing, not stdout and stderr.

Comment: The `Pod` will still have all the files in the containers too so you should be able to things like `kubectl cp curator-1499817660-6rzmf:var/log/myoutput.txt /tmp/myoutput.txt`

Comment: I'm not having any luck with rsh or cp       
`machine:~ user1$ oc rsh test-job-1502326800-f2qwv
error: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Succeeded`

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the OpenShift CLI, but assuming `rsh` is trying to execute something in the process that won't work. You need to copy the files out of the Pod (e.g `kubectl cp`). Does the OpenShift CLI support that? If not, can you use `kubectl`?

Comment: OpenShift CLI supports it. I tried running it, but nothing happened (no error, but no files copied either)

Comment: `machine:~ user1$ oc cp test-job-1502326800-f2qwv:/work/ImportantList.txt /work/ImportantList.txt`
`machine:~ user1$ cat /work/ImportantList.txt
cat: /work/ImportantList.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like maybe that file doesn't exist in the Pod. Try copying a file you know will exist (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) to make sure the `oc cp` part is working.

Comment: Turns out `kubectl cp` is a wrapper around the `kubectl exec` command and requires the `tar` binary be installed in your container. Since, as you've noted you `cannot exec into a container in a completed pod`, you cannot cp.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I hope this answer helps someone facing an *almost similar context*. For my case I needed to access some files generated by a CronJob and because the pod (and logs) are no longer accessible once the job completes I could not do so I was getting an error:

```
 kubectl logs mongodump-backup-29087654-hj89
Error from server (NotFound): pods "mongodump-backup-27640120-n8p7z" not found
```

My solution was to deploy a Pod that could access the PVC. The Pod runs a busybox image as below :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pvc-inspector
  namespace: demos
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: pvc-inspector
    command: ["tail"]
    args: ["-f", "/dev/null"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/tmp"
      name: pvc-mount
  volumes: 
  - name: pvc-mount
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mongo-backup-toolset-claim
```

After deploying this pod side by side to the CronJob I can exec into the pvc-inspector pod and then access files generated by the CronJob :

```
kubectl exec -it mongodump-backup-29087654-hj89 -- sh
cd tmp
ls
```

The pvc-inspector has to use the same persistentVolumeClaim as the CronJob and it also has to mount to the same directory as the CronJob.

The CronJob is a simple utility that is doing database backups of Mongo instances :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mongodump-backup
spec:
  schedule: "*/5  * * * *" #Cron job every 5 minutes
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 60
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongodump-backup
              image: golide/mongo-backup-toolset:0.0.2
              imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
              env:
                - name: DATABASE_NAME
                  value: "claims"
                - name:  MONGODB_URI
                  value: mongodb://root:mypasswordhere@mongodb-af1/claims
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: "/tmp"
                  name: mongodump-volume
              command: ['sh', '-c',"./dumpp.sh"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
            - name: mongodump-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: mongo-backup-toolset-claim
```